# desativar o espaço em branco ao final das linhas (não-arrasto-espaços)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho esse erro em um projeto **vue js**, sei que se trata **eslint** verifiquei o tutorial no site sobre como remover o erro com comando **--fix**, entretanto não surtiu efeito, se caso alguém conheça,  eu agradeço se poder ajudar.

**Erro:**

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/key-spacing    Missing space before value for key 'component'
  src\router\index.js:9:29
          {path:'/',component:Home}
                               ^

5 problems (5 errors, 0 warnings)

Errors:
  3  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/key-spacing
  1  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-spacing
  1  http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent

@ ./src/main.js 5:0-30
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js

> Listening at http://localhost:8080

**Vue js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    routes:[
        {path:'/',component:Home}
    ]
})
```

Comment: Qual foi o comando que usaste? Criei um ficheiro com o teu código e fiz `eslint eslinttest.js --fix` e funcionou bem

Comment: eslint --fix, neste caso devo selecionar o ficheiro que esta dando o erro

Comment: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent       Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 0
  src\router\index.js:11:1
  }
   ^
4 problems (4 errors, 0 warnings)

Comment: Usa o nome do ficheiro no comando: `eslint ./src/main.js --fix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa o nome do ficheiro no comando: `eslint ./src/main.js --fix`

Comment: Podias ter dito que [a minha sugestão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251957/desativar-o-espa%c3%a7o-em-branco-ao-final-das-linhas-n%c3%a3o-arrasto-espa%c3%a7os/253645#comment516993_251957) tinha  funcionado que eu dava uma resposta :)